# ¿Aplica modelo ARIMA a nuevos datos?

Tags: r

Estoy usando la paquetería "forecast" de R para ajustar modelos ARIMA a mis datos. En los modelos utilizo regresores externos de la siguiente forma:

```
library("forecast")
Modelo<-arima(log(Recupera), order=c(12,1,1), xreg = Colocacion, include.mean=FALSE)
```

Para hacer predicciones utilizo la siguiente instrucción:

```
Pronostico<-forecast(Modelo, xreg = Colocacion_Prueba)
```

Mi problema surge cuando quiero aplicar el modelo a datos actualizados:

```
Nuevo_Pronosostico<-forecast(object=log(Recupera_Actualizado), model=Modelo, xreg=Colocacion_Futura)
```

Pero me generar un error:

```
Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, xreg = xreg,  : 
  lengths of 'x' and 'xreg' do not match
```

He probado que en `xreg` se incluya toda la historia del regresor externo pero no me funciona.

Espero me puedan ayudar....

Comment: Por lo que dice la ayuda `xreg` debe tener la misma cantidad de filas de `x`, es decir `log(Recupera_Actualizado)` debe tener la misma cantidad de filas que `Colocacion_Futura`, verificalo y cualquier cosa nos cuentas. Saludos.

Comment: En caso de hacer que tengan la misma longitud, me arroja el siguiente error: `Error in forecast.Arima(fit, h = h, level = level, fan = fan) : 
  No regressors provided`, la verdad he intentando diferentes cosas pero nada me funciona.

Comment: El error de `forecast.Arima` es otro, en este caso lo que te está diciendo es que está esperando los regresores en parámetro `xreg` el cual por lo que veo no se lo estás pasando.

Comment: Estoy usando la misma instrucción que arriba `Nuevo_Pronosostico<-forecast(object=log(Recupera_Actualizado), model=Modelo, xreg=Colocacion_Futura` Sólo estoy haciendo que tengan el mismo número de filas object y xreg, por eso es que me confunde tanto. No veo qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Mira, lo que te puedo decir como programador (que es lo que soy) es que viendo el código de la función: `forecast.Arima` que es la del error: `Error in forecast.Arima(fit, h = h, level = level, fan = fan) `, el mensaje `No regressors provided` se corresponde siempre con  aquellos casos donde `xreg == NULL`.  `Colocacion_Futura` pareciera ser el problema, pero sin un ejemplo reproducible es muy dificíl poder ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Crees que me pueda poner en contacto contigo por otro medio para proporcionarte el ejemplo?

Comment: El tema es que no soy "estadístico", puedo analizar un tema desde el punto de vista del código, pero se me escaparán muchas cosas, te sugiero en la medida que no sean datos confidenciales, trates de agregar enlaces a los datos en la misma pregunta, vas a tener más chances de recibir una respuesta.

Comment: Si requieres ayuda desde el punto de vista estadístico, podría ayudarte, tengo experiencia con series de tiempo en R. No obstante, lo mejor siempre será que pongas ejemplos reproducibles, como bien señala Patricio.

Comment: Podría poner `head(datos)` y `str(datos)`, o una descripción detallada de ellos como longitud de la serie, si son mensuales y en que intervalo se mueven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logré resolver el problema, en realidad tenía que "actualizar" de cierta manera mi modelo. Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```
library("forecast")
Modelo<-arima(log(Recupera), order=c(12,1,1), xreg = Colocacion, include.mean=FALSE)
```

Una vez que tengo el modelo, lo debo actualizar a los últimos datos antes de hacer el forecast:

```
Modelo_Actualizado<-Arima(Log_Recuperacion_Actualizado, model=Modelo, xreg=Log_Colocacion_Actualizado)
```

Notar que la función que apliqué va con A mayúscula (no es la misma con la que se creó el modelo).

Después de esto, ya puedo hacer un forecast con el modelo actualizado:

```
  Pronostico<-forecast(Modelo_Actualizado, xreg=Log_Colocacion_Pronosicada)
```

Comment: Yo estaba mirando esta opción pero me asalta la duda: ¿no estarás modificando los coeficientes del anterior modelo con la nueva orden Arima al modificar los regresores y los datos? (es decir, que el Modelo_Actualizado mantiene el orden pero con otros coeficientes, por lo que no es el forecast que buscas)

Comment: De hecho no, el modelo actualizado conserva los coeficientes del modelo original, que justo es lo que estaba buscando. Lo puedes comprobar imprimiendo el valor del modelo actualizado.